# Regarding hidden field encryption & signing when SSL is used or not

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, encryption, signing

SSL is used during transport to prevent a third person from reading and modifying the transmitted data.

The user who sends data to the server and gets answers from the server, can obviously see and modify the data any way he or she wants. So the user can modify the hidden form field containing the view state. Base64 escaping does not offer any protection here, it is just a way to ensure that binary data is not messed up by character set conversations.

So in the likely case that your view state/hiddent field contains trustworthy information, that a malicious user must not modify, you need to enable encryption and signing for it.

### i have bit of confusion about the statement

it is just a way to ensure that binary data is not messed up by character set conversations.
what user trying to say "binary data is not messed up by character set conversations" any can explain it in more details.

how to enable encryption and signing for hiddent field?

how to sign a hiddent field? please guide me with all the steps to encryption and signing of hiddent field in asp.net MVC ?

thanks

Comment: Note that this is more a question for security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

As the user controls the browser there is little you can do against "malicious users". The only thing you can reliably do is to filter and double-check the input at the server side. If you really want to you can perform some obfuscation, but encryption and signing are not going to help you. In the worst case you will create trust in the send data where there is none.

Keep your server safe, perform good filtering preferably in a higher level language (without buffer overflows) and make sure your TLS setup is protected against the known attacks (e.g. the BEAST attack). That's the best you can do...

Comment: can u guide me how to filter and double-check the input at the server side ? and can u tell me how to obfuscation of data from server side. so when render at client side then it will be fully tamper proof & safe. thanks

Comment: should i post this question to security.stackexchange.com again for better answer??

Comment: @Mou In order, no, not possible and no, that would lead to duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MVC Security Extensions project https://mvcsecurity.codeplex.com.

Say the field you want to protect is Id...

On you controller post method add:

```
[ValidateAntiModelInjection("Id")]
```

Within your view add:

```
@Html.AntiModelInjectionFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
```

On post your Id field will be validated.